# IIS8 Asp.net State service remote connection failure

Tags: asp.net, iis

Recently we upgrade our web server to windows server 2012 with IIS8.

We have this issue when users try to connect the asp.net state service to this web server remotely.

It always popup

> Unable to make the session state request to the session state server.
>   Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the
>   client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote
>   machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the
>   value of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.
>   If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned
>   registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server
>   connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the
>   server name.

In IIS7 / 7.5 we use the same way and it works fine. As long as the state service is running and firewall is set properly, we don't have any problem. However, in IIS8 it doesn't work. (We even turn off firewall to test it)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to fix it.

1. Run Regedit
2. find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection
3. Set it to 1 instead of 0.
4. Restart asp.net state service.

It is so weird, I can't find anywhere to set this through interface. And I don't think I need to do this in IIS7 / 7.5.